# How to make firebase .observeSingleEventOf function run synchronously

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am running Firebase's `.getSingleEventOf` function to read data from my database in my program, and it is an asynchronous function. How would I make it synchronous (or make another synchronous function to house the code)?

I've tried to use the data passed through the function, but it hasn't been working! It only returns 0 elements, even though I know that I have data with the specific letters in my database.

```swift
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct CompeteUserFinderService {

    static func findCompetitors(contains letters: String?) -> [String] {
        //Make sure there was an input
        guard let letters = letters else { return [] }

        var usernames = [String]()

        //Database reference
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("usernames")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

            //Creates an array of all values in the usernames branch
            let value = Array((snapshot.value as! [String: Any]).keys)
            usernames = value.map { $0.lowercased() }.filter { $0.contains(letters.lowercased()) }

        }

        return usernames
    }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid doing synchronous calls in your iOS application. As of observeSingleEvents - the reason you might be getting empty result because that is what was previously cached. Also double check that your database security rules allow you to access "usernames" branch.

Comment: @interrupt, thank you for your feedback! I know for a fact that my security rules allow for access to the "usernames" branch, but what does it mean for something to be previously cached?